# Comparison of innerHTML with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to change `<p>` background according to its contact (`innerHTML`) but I cant get it to work.

```
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        if ($("p").innerHTML === "just a test"){
            $("p").css("background","yellow");
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>just a test number1</p>
<p>just a test number2</p>
<p>just a test</p>

<button>Execute</button>

</body>
```

I expected only the last `<p>` background to change but nothing happens, why is that?

Comment: Please include a Fiddle.

Comment: Please don't include a fiddle. You might want to use the Stackoverflow Snippet feature to turn your code into a live demo though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `innerHTML` property on a jQuery object, so `$("p").innerHTML === "just a test"` will always be `false`.

You could use `.html()` instead, but that would always return the data from *first* element that matched the selector, so it would still always be `false`.

Even if that wasn't the case, `$("p").css("background","yellow");` would set the background of *all* the paragraphs.

---

You need to loop over all the elements and test each one in turn.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("p").each(function(index, paragraph) {
      var $p = $(paragraph);
      if ($p.html() === "just a test") {
        $p.css("background", "yellow");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>just a test number1</p>
<p>just a test number2</p>
<p>just a test</p>

<button>Execute</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

InnerHtml is a JavaScript property, it does not belong in jQuery.

You need to change this:

```
 $("p").innerHTML === "just a test"
```

to this:

```
 $("p").html() === "just a test"
```

Secondly selector p is quite big, expecially that you are not calling it form any element, but in global scope. I would advise to use some sort of class or id, if it is possiblem.

Thirdly I would go with such fix to your algoritm:

```
$("p").each(function(){
   var el = $(this);
   if(el.htlm() === 'just a test'){ // could change for regexp (bevare of white characters)
      el.css("background","yellow")
   }
});
```

This way for every p element that inner html is 'just a test' you will change background color.